# boost asio example test fails

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am running a simple example of boost asio on fedora xfce..and it gives these errors ...any idea?

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    io_service.run();

    std::cout << "Do you reckon this line displays?" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
obj/Debug/main.o||In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':|
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp|214|undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'|
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp|215|undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'|
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp|216|undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'|
obj/Debug/main.o||In function `boost::system::error_code::error_code()':|
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp|315|undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'|
obj/Debug/main.o||In function `boost::asio::error::get_system_category()':|
/usr/include/boost/asio/error.hpp|216|undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'|
||=== Build finished: 5 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 1 seconds) ===|
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I compiled and linked your test program as-is under Windows 8 using Boost 1.49, with no compilation errors.  So at least you know there is nothing organically wrong with your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to link to `libboost_system`, e.g. `c++ you-file.cxx -lboost_system`

Comment: Check codeblocks documentations http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=FAQ-Compiling_(general)#Q:_I_would_like_to_compile_a_project_using_some_non-standard_libraries._How_can_I_indicate_to_CodeBlocks_that_these_libraries_and_include_files_exist.3F